# How to implement a drop shadow with rounded corner in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement the drop shadow and **rounded corner** in `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MembershipCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect rect = cell.frame;
    UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,8,rect.size.width-8,rect.size.height)];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
    [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
}
```

I am using the above code but it shows the shadow in the top and left side of the cell.

Comment: did not getting your question but are looking for the `shadowRadius`?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you dont have space on right and bottom, you need to have some space at right and bottom as well for shadow to show up. Also, you can add `shadowRadius` to the layer for controlling the radius of the shadow. Try following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MembershipCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect rect = cell.frame;

    UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView;

    if (![cell.contentView viewWithTag:SOME_TAG_VALUE]) {

        whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,8,rect.size.width-16,rect.size.height-16)];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.tag = SOME_TAG_VALUE;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
    }

    [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
}
```

Comment: This solution is correct. However, it's advised you subclass the cell, and do this in `awakeFromNib` or `initWithCoder...`. So that you don't create and add subviews while scrolling. I have added a crude condition to check if `whiteRoundedCornerView` is already added.

Comment: I completely agree.